# Stop previous loops and only run the last one

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following macro. As a short description, every time you select a new cell, it puts a reference text in the status-bar, as a scrolling text. I make it so it does not disrupt user input by using "Do... While loop" with "Do events", will share the code below. 
The problem is if i quickly click on multiple cells, it remembers previous loops and runs them all. How can I set the macro to stop running all the loops except for the last one?

```
Option Explicit

Public STATUSTEXT As String
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  STATUSTEXT = "Some text valid only for current selection"
  'FILL THE TEXT AND GOTO EXIT SUB TO SKIP RELEASING STATUSBAR
  charTotal = Len(STATUSTEXT)
  charI = 1

  Do
    charI = charI + 1
    Application.statusBar = Right(STATUSTEXT, charI)
    DoEvents    '@ IMPORTANT
  Loop Until charI >= charTotal

  Application.statusBar = STATUSTEXT

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not check if target.count>1 and exit if so.

Comment: Can you explain that? *"it remembers previous loops and runs them all."* That should not be possible because VBA does not support multi-threading. That means VBA code runs one after the other but not at the same time.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I also thought that VBA does not support multi threading. but I think this is an exception. Just as proof, put this code in a sheet with some names on column A, and return them in STATUSTEXT variable, but first put the STATUSTEXT inside "Worksheet_SelectionChange" and not as a global variable, and quickly use Arrow Down key to go through them. What you will notice is that Excel displays in sequence all the names you scrolled through,but does not stop at the last text, this is why i had to use a global variable. It should stop at the last name, but it stops at the longest.

Comment: This happends not because of multi threading, but because of what PEH said. You are updating the Status bar to often. When you hit the arrow key and scroll down, the scroll bar will update each character in the text and then go to the next event. So basically there is a queue of events which will be processed one after each other.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @MG92, Do you have any ideas on what trigger i could use to get out of the loop if it's not the last keystroke, to avoid overloading the Statusbar?

Comment: As it's been explained that this is happening because loops are being stacked. What you could do is after `DoEvents`, check if `Target.Address` is the same as `ActiveCell.Address`. If it's not, exit sub

Answer (score 1):

Ok I try a better explanation of what actually happens.

Your arrow down triggers the event `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. Then this macro runs and gets into the loop with `DoEvents`. This `DoEvents` allows you to move your cursor again and to do other events. That means your first `SelectionChange` gets actually halted at `DoEvents` and second `SelectionChange` triggers. After this second event is finished you will get back to the `DoEvents` of the first `SelectionChange` event and it continues until the end.

So what happens your events get stacked because VBA cannot multi-thread. It just halts the first macro at `DoEvents` triggers the next event and continues the first event after:

```
1. SelectionChange
   2. SelectionChange
      3. SelectionChange
         …
      3. SelectionChange Ends
   2. SelectionChange Ends
1. SelectionChange Ends
```

So it looks like the first `SelectionChange` event run last just becaus it run the others in between. Note this is no multi-threading, the code was halted.

The actual issue came from your `DoEvents` if you remove it. Excel blocks the user interface untile the first `SelectionChange` event is finished and does not allow to run another event until the first finished. And whoops you will see it ends where your cursor stopped. But it is slow becaus it waits for the event until it performs the next arrow down.

So actually you just need to cancel the first event in case another event run. Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public GlobalStatusText As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim PrivateStatusText As String
    PrivateStatusText = "Some text valid only for current selection " & Target.Address
    GlobalStatusText = PrivateStatusText

    Dim charTotal As Long, charI As Long
    charTotal = Len(GlobalStatusText)
    charI = 1

    Do
        charI = charI + 1
        Application.StatusBar = Right(GlobalStatusText, charI)
        DoEvents    '@ IMPORTANT
        If GlobalStatusText <> PrivateStatusText Then Exit Sub 'cancel because another event run inbetween
    Loop Until charI >= charTotal

    Application.StatusBar = GlobalStatusText
End Sub
```

This will cancel the previous events if another event changed the status text in between.